# override all files and folders while unziping except given folder name using php

Tags: php, unzip

My file structure in zip is

```
lib
css
js
app1
app2
index.php
```

All the above files and folders are in test.zip

i want to extract this test.zip using php

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open("test.zip");
    if ($res === TRUE)
        {
            $zip->extractTo('path');
            $zip->close();
        }
```

**if lib folder is already exist in the directory where we are unzipping then  except `lib(folder)` all other files and folders should get override.**

how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php , on open, pass in the over write flag.

Comment: if i use the above code all the files and folders are getting override but i don't want to override lib folder. is there any way to escape this folder from override.

Comment: Hmmm.. Extract to a tmp folder then use php.net/exec to cp the folders over except lib? I can provide an example if that thought process makes sense.